# MySQL string comparison query giving either unexpected double or unknown column error

Tags: mysql

I am having problems getting a very simple MySQL query to work. I am searching a table for a row where a string field has a certain value. If the string I am comparing against is in quotes I get an "Unknown column" error. If the string is not in quotes I get an "Illegal double error".

The queries I am making are (no quotes):

```
SELECT * FROM `userprofile_userprofile` WHERE `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` = 4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5
```

and (with quotes around the string):

```
SELECT * FROM `userprofile_userprofile` WHERE `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` = `4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5`
```

This is my table and content:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `userprofile_userprofile`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `userprofile_userprofile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firebaseUID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `userprofile_userprofile_user_id_59dda034_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `userprofile_userprofile`
--

LOCK TABLES `userprofile_userprofile` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `userprofile_userprofile` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `userprofile_userprofile` VALUES (1,'bdbe350a-9c96-4cc0-94f1-5406a9aaa3e7',17),(2,'4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5',18);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `userprofile_userprofile` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I dont see the quotes around the string in the second query? You might be mistaking quotes for backticks

Comment: Just edited the question to show the quotes.

Comment: As I  suspected those are backticks

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the string single quotes (`''`) and not in backticks (``) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `userprofile_userprofile` 
WHERE `userprofile_userprofile`.`firebaseUID` = '4929e406-9d75-43e2-afa4-fe641f3e85f5'
```